# Link the hints to solve this one, starting with Michael Jackson

Tags: logical-deduction, connections-puzzle

This is a linking puzzle, where you get 8 hints, and 7 links between them.

1. Michael Jackson made a song for this film.

1.-2. The link between the animal of clue 1 and the fictional person of clue 2 is an animal with long teeth.

2. This is a fictional person, and the same in both links.

2.-3. This is the best couple of friends you ever knew.

3. This is a fictional person in the foregoing link, but a real person in the next link.

3.-4. They used to be a super-couple.

4. A real person in both link, but he could also be associated with the name of a certain part of the heel.

4.-5. The new super-couple. Lots of kids.

5. Change a vowel in one of the names from the last link, to identify the fictional person in the next link.

5.-6. Worlds most famous lovers.

6. This person has portrayed both the fictional person in the last link, and the next link. He has the name of a turtle.

6.-7. The ship is sinking.

7. A fictional person in last link, a real in the next one.

7.-8. A royal couple.

8. A person from Switzerland.

**The two overflowing words from 1. and 8. could be combined to be associated with a principle important to many countries in the world. This has recently(?) been a part of news coverage around the world. What is this principle called?**

Comment: 5.-6.: Romeo and Juliet

Comment: 6.-7.: Titanic ${}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete solution (I have added my solutions for items 1 through 3 to Bulldogg6404's solution for items 4-8):

> * 1:   "Free Willy" (about saving an Orca whale)
>  * 1-2: Walrus
>  * 2:   Ross Geller (from the TV series "Friends"; played by David Schwimmer)
>  * 2-3: Ross & Rachel = David Schwimmer & Jennifer Aniston (TV series "Friends")
>  * 3:   Jennifer Aniston (plays Rachel in "Friends")
>  * 3-4: Brad Pitt and Jennifer Aniston
>  * 4:   Brad Pitt plays Achilles in the movie "Troy"
>  * 4-5: Brad Pitt and Angelina Jolie
>  * 5:   Jolie -> Julie (?)
>  * 5-6: Romeo and Juliet
>  * 6:   Leonardo Dicaprio portrayed main characters in both films
>  * 6-7: Titanic
>  * 7:    Kate Winslet (actress in Titanic)
>  * 7-8:  Kate Middleton and Prince William
>  * 8:    William Tell (folk tale legend from Switzerland)

The answer to the final question seems to be

> the **freedom of speech** principle
>   (This works with "telling" and with "Free" Willy)

Comment: I looked up the *Friends* characters, and I figure Rachel's best friend would more likely be Monica Geller. I also figured the first hint was about *Free Willy*, but I couldn't make a connection between the whale/orca and Monica Geller...  
Also, the final question answer would use the words **Free** and **Tell**; whatever a Free Tell principle is, I don't know.

Comment: Remember, "Will" is not part of the final answer *at all*, because the riddle says to use the *overflow* words. Those would be the words at each end of the link chain - the very first word and the very last word.

Comment: Can you explain the connection between Ross and walrus, please? Is it that they sound alike? Or is it some reference to the show that I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: "Whale + Ross" sounds similar to "walrus".

Comment: @Bulldogg6404 whale-walrus-Ross is indeed the weakest link in the chain (as I anticipated). But the chain still survived...:-)

Comment: Yes, I see it now. :P I wouldn't have thought of it myself because a) my pronunciations of whale, Ross, and walrus would never have connected; and b) I was convinced that the best couple of friends were Rachel and Monica, referring to the term "couple" as simply the number 2. Kudos, Gamow. :)

Answer (score 6):

These are the pieces I figured out.
Edit: New ideas for links 1-3.

> 1   : *Free Willy*
>  1-2 : Movie is about an orca/whale, which has surprisingly long teeth and is rather fatty.
>  2   : Monica Geller (*Friends* wiki says she was considered overweight in high school. compared to a whale... a fat joke?)
>  2-3 : Monica Geller and Rachel Green from *Friends*
>  3   : Rachel Green played by Jennifer Aniston
>  3-4 : Brad Pitt and Jennifer Aniston
>  4   : Brad Pitt plays Achilles in the movie *Troy*.
>  4-5 : Brad Pitt and Angelina Jolie
>  5   : Jolie -> Julie (?)
>  5-6 : *Romeo and Juliet*
>  6   : Leonardo Dicaprio portrayed main characters in both films (Leonardo is the name of a Ninja Turtle)
>  6-7 : *Titanic*
>  7   : Kate (Winslet is the actress in Titanic)
>  7-8 : Kate Middleton and Prince William
>  8   : William Tell (folk tale legend from Switzerland)
>
>  Final answer is **Free Tell**, also known as Freedom of Speech.

Comment: You are good! Just solve part 1.-3. and then you will nail it!

Comment: Updated the answer. The only thing I'm not confident in is the Orca -> Monica Geller link. I made my best guess based on my absolute zero knowledge of the *Friends* television series, so I hope it's right. :)